# Java Scripting Engine importing my classes does not work

Tags: java, scriptengine

A code is worth 1000 words of explaining it :-)

```
package jasim;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class JSTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine jse = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");

        jse.eval("println(new jasim.JSTest().toString)");

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JSTest Object";
    }
}
```

This code will fail with the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "jasim" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

How do I import my own classes into the ScriptEngine?

Comment: A code is worth 1000 words of explaining it .Thumbs up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the [Mozilla Rhino docs](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html), the solution is either to use:

`importPackage(Packages.jasim)` within the script, or to use `new Packages.jasim.JSTest()`

This is not so clear in the Sun docs regarding the importPackage in the ScriptingEngine docs.

Comment: The documentation notes that _"The class provides additional `importPackage()` and `importClass()`  global functions for scripts but their extensive usage has tendency to pollute the global name space with names of Java classes and prevents loaded classes from garbage collection."_ You would probably be better off using `JavaImporter`.

Answer (score -4):

The same way you import `javax.script.ScriptEngine;`...

Just make sure your classes are in the CLASSPATH

Comment: they are in the classpath, but not visible in the JavaScript runtime.